# How do I provide a default value for a web api function parameter?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following function in my controller:

```
[HttpGet("ExerciseListWithHash")]
public object GetExerciseListWithHash(string hashString = "")
{
    return DL.GetExerciseListWithHash(hashString);
}
```

When I run the application and Swagger comes up, if I try to execute that function without providing a parameter the response shown in Swagger is:

> Error: response status is 400

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-374015b9a04f6f82b0eb4d564ac89807-bdae114f0a4577c8-00",
  "errors": {
    "hashString": [
      "The hashString field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried giving `hashString` a default value of null or empty string and either way it fails. How do I make the parameter optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `.NET6`/`.NET7`. From `.NET 6` **the non-nullable property must be required**, otherwise the ModelState will be invalid.

To achieve your requirement, **one way** is you can remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file(double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File).

**The other way** is just add the `?` to allow nullable:

```
[HttpGet("ExerciseListWithHash")]
public object GetExerciseListWithHash(string? hashString)  //get default value null
//public object GetExerciseListWithHash(string? hashString="") get default value ""
{
    return DL.GetExerciseListWithHash(hashString);
}
```

**Note: The third way** is that you can remove the `[ApiController]` to skip the validation in client side, but if you need judge the `ModelState.IsValid` in the server side, it would be false.

Answer (score 1):

To make it optional just configure the parameter in the attribute and add a question mark.

```
[HttpGet("ExerciseListWithHash/{hashString?}")]
public object GetExerciseListWithHash(string hashString = "")
{
    return DL.GetExerciseListWithHash(hashString);
}
```

For default values

```
[HttpGet("ExerciseListWithHash/{hashString=default}")]
public object GetExerciseListWithHash(string hashString)
{
    return DL.GetExerciseListWithHash(hashString);
}
```

More about route configuration can be found in the documentation - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-templates)

For swagger it won't work I guess because it is not supported.
More information can be found [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2371)